# Ruby on Rails Routing, Double Nested Slugs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm trying to setup the basic routing and URLs of my application. I'm using the FriendlyId gem to have nicer looking URLs.

In my model design an Account has Users, and an Account has Farms. When a User signs in, I want to redirect them to `myapp.com/account-name`. This page should be an index page of that account's farms, along with some other options. When they click on a farm, I want the page to go to `myapp.com/account-name/farm-name`.

How do I do this? Is this just totally anti-RESTful to not include /account or /farms in the URL? If it is, then what can I do to have the url be `myapp.com/account-name/farms/farm-name`?

Right now I have it correctly showing `myapp.com/account-name` by having

```
get "/:id", to: "accounts#show", as: 'account'
```

but I don't think I can extend that to include farms. I think it may be solved with something like

```
resource :account do
    resource :farms
end
```

But that shows `myapp.com/account.account-name` when I go to the account, and when I do something like `redirect_to account_path(current_user.account)` it uses the POST route instead of the GET one.

I'm decently new at Rails, so sorry for misunderstandings. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If `Farm belongs_to Account` (as opposed to [HABTM](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)), [shallow nesting](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) might be a good route structure.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that I can do this by adding one more line in the routes file

```
get "/:account_slug/:id", to: "farms#show", as: 'account_farm'
```

Then I can link to a farm in the view with

```
<%= link_to farm.name, account_farm_path(account_slug: @account.slug, id: farm.slug)
```

I'm still interested in any answers about if this is good practice or not, or any other recommendations.